# How to use InterWiki links in moinmoin?

Tags: python, wiki, moinmoin

We use a number of diffrent web services in our company, wiki(moinmoin), bugtracker (internally), requestracker (customer connection), subversion. Is there a way to parse the wikipages so that if I write "... in Bug1234 you could ..." Bug1234 woud be renderd as a link to `http://mybugtracker/bug1234`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the interwiki page in moinmoin, (most wikis have them) we use trac for example and you can set up different link paths to point to your different web resources.  So in our Trac you can go [[SSGWiki:Some Topic]] and it will point to another internal wiki.

Answer (score 0):

add to the file `data/intermap.txt` (create if not existing, but that should not happen) a line like

```
wpen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
```

so that you can write `[[wpen:MoinMoin]]` instead of `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoinMoin`

I also have

```
wpfr http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/
wpde http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/
```

the `data/intermap.txt` gives also other examples that serve just like bookmarklets in firefox. in your case, using :

```
tracker http://mybugtracker/
```

you would issue `[[tracker:bug1234]]`

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the solution. 
"Add the site to data/intermap.txt" found at:

http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinQuestions#MoinMoinQuestions.2BAC8-Administration.Howtoaddnewinterwikisites.3F